# Create N*M <table> in view by iterating through model items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-views

Well, easily I have a model:

```
@model IEnumerable<CompanyWebSite.Category>
```

And it's quite straightforward to iterating through its items and create a **One-item-per-row** table to show them.

And the problem is that I want to create a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    //
    // ...
    //
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> ... LastItem ...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Seems simple, but I can't do that...!

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Products";
var last = Model.Last();
int i = 1;
}

<table id="tblCats">
@foreach(var item in Model)
{                        
    if (i == 1){
        <tr>
        @(i = 2)
    }

        @if (!item.Equals(last))
        {                                            
            <td>
                <a href="#"><h4>@item.CategoryName</h4></a>
                <label>@item.Description</label>
            </td>   
            if (i == 2)
            {
                </tr>
                i = 1;
            }
            else
                i = 2;         
        }
        else
        {
            <td colspan="2">

            </td>
            </tr>
        }                                                                                                  
}
```

Because of the first opening `<tr>`, Razor gets confused and doesn't see the closing `}`s and `else` statements... What can I do...?!

Comment: Try surrounding the <tr> with <text> </text> that should help Razor figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [HtmlHelper.Raw method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to help razor

Comment: Thanks! actually @juhan_h's comment is right too, but I do not like using <text> marker, as it makes code look ugly